# Unexpected token ( with xmlstarlet

Tags: bash, xpath, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I am trying to parse a XML file with xmlstarlet (using xpath), but I get a syntax error and I don't know how to correct my code.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1=="author" ]; then
    xmlstarlet sel  -t -v //topic/auteur[text()=$2]/../titre < ~/.jvc/topics.xml
fi
```

And this is the XML file:

```
<liste_topics>
  <topic>
    <icone>topic_marque_on</icone>
    <auteur>Knakis</auteur>
    <titre>Vos bureaux</titre>
    <auteur_en_rouge>0</auteur_en_rouge>
    <nb_reponses>1036</nb_reponses>
    <lien_topic>jv://forums/1-38-7790682-1-0-1-0-0.xml</lien_topic>
    <date_heure>29/08/2014 - 12h56</date_heure>
  </topic>
  <topic>
    <icone>topic_marque_on</icone>
    <auteur>ShadowwF</auteur>
    <titre>[PROJET] Le wiki du forum v2</titre>
    <auteur_en_rouge>0</auteur_en_rouge>
    <nb_reponses>198</nb_reponses>
    <lien_topic>jv://forums/1-38-7796926-1-0-1-0-0.xml</lien_topic>
    <date_heure>17/08/2014 - 15h16</date_heure>
  </topic>
  <topic>
    <icone>topic_marque_off</icone>
    <auteur>Google_Bot</auteur>
    <titre>[À lire] Répondre aux trolls = kick</titre>    
    <nb_reponses>0</nb_reponses>
    <lien_topic>jv://forums/1-38-7818336-1-0-1-0-0.xml</lien_topic>
    <date_heure>14/08/2014 - 03h33</date_heure>
  </topic>
</liste_topics>
```

I want to print the text between the "titre" tag which author (text between "auteur value") is the second parameter. For example, if I enter `./my_script author Knakis`, I want it to return :

```
Vos bureaux
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Use spaces for the elements within `[ ]`: `if [ $1 == "author" ]; then`.

Comment: What is it supposed to do ? I did it but it changed nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only xmllint:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "author" ]; then
  xmllint --xpath "//liste_topics/topic[auteur=\"$2\"]/titre/text()" file.xml
fi
```

Output:

```
 Vos bureaux
```